# Checar se arquivo foi criado

Tags: php

Fiz uma função que cria um arquivo no php, mas preciso que ela retorne `true` caso tenha dado tudo certo ou `false` caso um dos passos tenha falhado. Resolvi da seguinte maneira:

```
function createFile($path, $nome, $content){
    if (!($fp = fopen($path.$nome,"wb")))
        return false;
    if (!fwrite($fp,$content))
        return false;
    if (!fclose($fp))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Existe uma forma mais limpa de fazer isso?

O problema de usar `file_exists` é que não vou saber se deu erro no `fwrite` por exemplo. Estava pensando se não existe algo como um `try()catch()` mas com erros ao invés de exceções.

Comment: O problema de usar `file_exists` é que não vou saber se deu erro no `fwrite` por exemplo. Estava pensando se não existe algo como um `try()catch()` mas com erros ao invés de exceções.

Comment: Se eu fizer dessa forma que você falou consigo ter certeza de que o if vai executar as funções na ordem certa?

Comment: Bom, se for pra perder legibilidade vou deixar da forma que está por enquanto. Vou pesquisa sobre o `try()catch()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplificando

```
function createFile($path, $nome, $content){
    return file_put_contents($path.$nome, $content);
}
```

A função [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) retorna booleano *false* em caso de erro. Do contrário, retornará a quantidade de bytes escrito no arquivo.

Isso é basicamente o que retorna da função [fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php), a qual necessita do retorno de [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Contudo, não quer dizer que é mais performático por ter menos códigos. Normalmente `fopen()`, `fwrite()` e `fclose()` custam menos. Porém, para um único processo é uma diferença de custo irrisório.

Caso queira manter o código da pergunta e dar mais consistência, poderia adicionar uma quarta condicional, verificando o resource:

```
function createFile($path, $nome, $content){
    if (!($fp = fopen($path.$nome,"wb")))
        return false;
    if (!fwrite($fp,$content))
        return false;
    if (!fclose($fp))
        return false;
    if (!is_resource($fp))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Mas nesse caso é algo um tanto incomum. Pode acontecer em ambientes específicos onde o `fclose()` retorna `true` e o resource mantém-se ainda ativo. Nesse caso a função [is_resource()](http://php.net/is_resource) pode ser útil.

A função `file_put_contents()` simplifica tudo isso. Afinal, o resultado será o mesmo.

Note também que o nome da função que criaste é `createFile()`, no entanto há diversas operações que podem retornar resultados diferentes que podem não ser necessariamente relacionados ao que a nomenclatura da função diz "criar arquivo".

Se quer um retorno minucioso, poderia criar um array contendo o retorno de cada função, pois uma situação que pode ocorrer é o arquivo ser criado e o conteúdo gravado corretamente e, apenas falhar no `fclose()`. Mas da forma como está, uma falha no `fclose()` retornaria `false` e você fica sem saber de onde proveio o valor `false`.

Poderia implementar algo desse tipo:

```
function createFile($path, $nome, $content){
    $rs = array(
        'fopen' => null,
        'fwrite' => null,
        'fclose' => null
    );
    if (($rs['fopen'] = fopen($path.$nome, 'wb')) !== false) {
        $rs['fwrite'] = fwrite($rs['fopen'], $content);

        // Invoque fclose() independente do resultado de fwrite().
        $rs['fclose'] = fclose($fp);
    }
    return $rs;
}
```

Note que que `fclose()` é invocado independente do retorno de `fwrite()`. Isso porque mesmo se `fwrite()` falhar o resource de `fopen()` permanecerá aberto. Na versão original da pergunta isso não acontece. Você tem um pequeno leak.

Mas ainda sugeriria mudar o nome da função, pois não está apenas criando um arquivo. Está também inserindo dados. Para um createfile, o ideal seria também checar se o diretório é um path válido antes mesmo de invocar `fopen()`. Dando mais consistência a função. Pode ser o caso de pensar em OOP para organizar melhor e evitar esse "espaguete" de códigos.

Se você me perguntar se eu faço isso na vida real. Não, eu não faço. Aplico apenas o `file_put_contents()` para ser feliz. Pois na maioria dos casos não precisa de tanta complicação. Exceto, é claro, para casos onde realmente exige-se uma real necessidade em criar uma rotina "altamente" consistente.

Comment: +1, ficou bem objetiva, e mencionou vários pontos importantes de uma maneira bem sucinta, sem excesso de informação paralela.